# Loading View programatically takes too long

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a table from an array. However, loading it takes a bit too long. Is there a way to speed it up?

`allData` contains about 250 arrays

Function to generate rows

```
renderRow = (num,one,three,four,five) => {
  return (
    <View key={num} style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 0.5, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>{num}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>{one}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>{three}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>{four}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>{five}</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Displaying the table is what takes about 5 seconds

```
DrawSchedule = () => {

  var allData = this.state.allData;
  var Rows = [];
  var Table = [];

  allData.map((datum) => {
      Rows.push(this.renderRow(datum[0],datum[1],datum[3],datum[4],datum[5]));
  })

  Table = [];

  Table.push(
    <View key="head" style={styles.tableContainer}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 0.5, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
              <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Title A</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
              <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Title B</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
              <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Title C</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
              <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Title D</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }}>
              <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Title E</Text>
            </View>
      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>  
            {Rows}
        </View>
    </View>     
  )

  this.state.Table = Table;
  this.setState({Table: this.state.Table});

}

render() {
  return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView>
        <Button
          style={styles.loginButton}
          onPress={this.DrawSchedule}
          title="Load Data"
        />
      {this.state.Table}
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a [`FlatList`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) or any of the other List type components that are designed to handle rendering only what is needed on the screen? Just rendering everything at once will of course take a long time as you're rendering a ton of components including what isn't even shown on the screen yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FlatList` to render large list for performance:

```
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';

render() {
    return (
        <FlatList
            data={this.state.data}
            keyExtractor={(item) => ....}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <View>
                    ...
                </View>
            )}
        />
    );
}
```

Please read [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html)